# Selecting distinct on where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using following query to select certain values

```
select 
    sb.company
    ,b.id  as Id
    ,bds.id as PId
    ,brp.bId
from supp b
left outer join sales bds on (bds.sId = b.id)
left outer join tperiod brp on (brp.id = bds.rId)
left outer join tbuyer sb on (sb.id = brp.bId)
where  
    b.ownerId = @oId;
```

In `where b.ownerId = @old`  ownerId has multiple same values in the column, I want to select distinct or unique on it. So that query is done on distinct ownerId only.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

For example : column `ownerId` has values

```
2231
2231
2231
3341
2231
```

So I want the query to use only 2231 once rather than for all occurrences of 2231

Comment: Can you share an example to illustrate what do you want to get and what did you get back instead?

Comment: Please consider to post sample data and desired output based on it to illustrate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yes, i can't understand either. sample data would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to select the values based on Owner ID uniqueness, you have use group by clause and give "distinct" in select clause like

```
select distinct
   sb.company
   ,b.id  as Id
   ,bds.id as PId
   ,brp.bId
from supp b
left outer join sales bds on (bds.sId = b.id)
left outer join tperiod brp on (brp.id = bds.rId)
left outer join tbuyer sb on (sb.id = brp.bId)
where  b.ownerId = @oId
group by b.ownerId
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to user GROUP BY on the ownerId, but then you will need to use some aggregate function on all the other fields in the select statment

If you want a unique ownerId and the other related fields are different, SQL needs to know what to display.  Do you just want the MAX value on the related fields?  You are asking for a unique value for the owner, so what do you just want to display if the joined fields have different values for that ownerId?

This is something that could work, depending on what you want.

```
select 
 MAX(sb.company)
,MAX(b.id)  as Id
,MAX(bds.id) as PId
,MAX(brp.bId)
from supp b
  left outer join sales bds on (bds.sId = b.id)
  left outer join tperiod brp on (brp.id = bds.rId)
  left outer join tbuyer sb on (sb.id = brp.bId)
where  
  b.ownerId = @oId
GROUP BY b.ownerId
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way………….
get the @oid inside the table Input_table and join with the table Supp.

> select 
>       sb.company
>       ,b.id  as Id
>       ,bds.id as PId
>       ,brp.bId from
>
> (select max(b.ownerId) ownerId from supp where b.ownerId = @oId;)
>   Input_table
>
> Inner Join supp b on temp_tab.ownerId = b.ownerId left outer join
>   sales bds on (bds.sId = b.id) left outer join tperiod brp on (brp.id =
>   bds.rId) left outer join tbuyer sb on (sb.id = brp.bId)

Sorry for bad format !